# Transferring a property with personal mortgage to an LLC through a land trust

Tags: united-states, rental-property, trusts-and-estates, limited-liability-company

Let's say one has a property with a personal mortgage on it. This question is about transferring the property to an LLC. In order to avoid triggering accelerated mortgage payment, this is often done through first transferring the property to a land trust which it protects from the acceleration under Garn-St. Germain Act.

- Given that your name is already associated with property through a regular mortgage, does transferring property to a land trust and then LLC provide enough obfuscation for avoiding personal liabilities in the case you get sued by someone (like a tenant)? (In other words does forming an LLC in this situation provide any benefits?)
- I am not aware of the exact process of transferring to a land trust but I imagine that would be like selling your property to a different entity. Can this trigger re-financing? (In other words does Garn-St. Germain Act. protect you from re-financing or it is possible to get forced to re-finance your mortgage?)

Comment: Your first step is to read your loan documents and see what it says.  It almost certainly has a "balance due on sale" clause and the lender will not release the mortgage unless the loan is satisfied.  That being said, you may be able to negotiate the terms provided that the lender still holds the mortgage.  But most likely it's been resold and there is no option to change the terms.

Comment: @jwh20 It does have, but the land trust is there to avoid that. I was told that is the whole point of transferring to land trust first to circumvent that clause.

Comment: @user127776  The land trust would be in big trouble if it was used to circumvent a contract.

Comment: @Mary Yes normally, but that is the whole point behind [Garn-St. Germain Act.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garn%E2%80%93St._Germain_Depository_Institutions_Act)